# Android browsers supports webkit css?

Tags: android, css, webkit

I want my website to be able to display some webkit based css properties.
Do android browsers support web kit?
I mean all browser available for android like basic browser and oter browser available in market

Comment: [TIAS](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tias)

Comment: Android's web browser is based on Webkit.

Comment: yea but other browsers like skyfire,dolpin etc (not firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do android browsers support web kit?

Not all of them. For example, Firefox for the desktop does not use WebKit; Firefox Mobile does not use WebKit.

Comment: @pahnin: Contact their developers and ask. AFAIK neither of those are open source.